# 同じ文字列を検索し、並び替える方法ありますか？

Tags: excel

A列に順番の数字。B列に北海道〜沖縄まで入力がしてある。(一般的に統計調査にあるようなの順)
C列に、ある項目の都道府県ランキング(数値あり)が入力してある。

A    B        C

1  北海道　宮崎県(63.4)
2  青森県　・・・(62.2)
〜　　〜
47 沖縄県　・・・(45.2)

C列を関数を使って、B列と同じにように並び替えるにはどうすればいいか。
簡単な方法があれば、教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 無事並び替えることができました。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず C 列を都道府県名と数値に分けて 2 列にします。そのあと B 列の都道府県名を使って VLOOKUP するとよいです。